# How to dynamically add a class method?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Using the Objective-C Runtime, how do I add the method `+layerClass` to the private `UIGroupTableViewCellBackground` class (not to its superclass, `UIView`)? Note: This is only for testing (to see how `UITableViewStyleGrouped` sets cell `backgroundView` & `selectedBackgroundView`).

Comment: are you taking to yourself ? Q/A? posted answer by youfself after 5 mins?

Comment: @samfisher: This is a perfectly legitimate thing to do: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2706/ Matt is just adding to the repository of information.

Comment: thanks @JoshCaswell for enlighten me on this..!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To dynamically add a class method, instead of an instance method, use `object_getClass(cls)` to get the meta class and then add the method to the meta class. E.g.:

```
UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE Class my_layerClass(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    return [MyLayer class];
}

+ (void)initialize {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = object_getClass(NSClassFromString(@"UIGroupTableViewCellBackground"));
        NSAssert(class_addMethod(class, @selector(layerClass), (IMP)my_layerClass, "@:@"), nil);
    });
}
```

You might also be able to do this easier by adding the `+layerClass` method to a category of `UIGroupTableViewCellBackground` and using a forward class definition, i.e. `@class UIGroupTableViewCellBackground`, to get it to compile.

Comment: Also #include <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 1):

Try this magic:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

+ (void)load {
    class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass("UIGroupTableViewCellBackground"), 
        @selector(layerClass), (IMP)my_layerClass, "@:@");
}
```